# The batch of store 's sync in the Extjs

Tags: extjs, store

I have meet one problem that :

there are three store in my formpanel in one page.
 store1，store2，store3.
 now I need to sync all the stores in one function .
 but ,as you knew ,the sync is synchronized .so i don't knew which store is sync last.
I need knew that,because I want to output some success information in the callback of the last sync.
 can I use the the Ext.data.Batch,to solve the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

you need sync with batch, but I don't know how to implemented.

In my app I need 3 stores ready before to render my grid so I make:

```
    launch: function(){
        myMask = new Ext.LoadMask(document.body,{msg:"Cargando recursos..."});
        myMask.show();
        Ext.create('tsjdf.store.catalogo.secretarias').load({
            scope: this,
            callback: this.onStoresReady
        });Ext.create('tsjdf.store.catalogo.organos').load({
            scope: this,
            callback: this.onStoresReady
        });Ext.create('tsjdf.store.libro.ejemplo').load({
            scope: this,
            callback: this.onStoresReady
        }); 
    },
    onStoresReady: function(){
        if( 1
            & !Ext.StoreManager.get('catalogo.secretarias').isLoading() 
            & !Ext.StoreManager.get('catalogo.SiNo').isLoading() 
            & !Ext.StoreManager.get('catalogo.organos').isLoading() 
            & !Ext.StoreManager.get('libro.ejemplo').isLoading() 

        ){
        //al stores ready, I can continue
        }
```

I hope it help you